# Android AVD Device won't use a Google API Target and Intel CPU at the same time

Tags: android, google-api, android-virtual-device, haxm

I wanted to take advantage of HAXM but when I select a Google API as a target, the Intel chip option for the CPU is gone and the select list is disabled with ARM selected.  If I choose a none Google API of the same version it is selectable.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the HAXM for the GOOGLE API !

**GOOGLE API -> ARM (FORCED)** can't use Virtualization.

**ANDROID API -> ARM / INTEL ATOM (ANY)**

Comment: Well that sucks. I can't run it with my project then.

Comment: Using phone instead of an emulator is more convenient!

Comment: That sucks. So in other words, anything that we need to test on Google Play Services, like the Maps API, cannot use the Intel Atom HAXM?