# Android Studio - AVD never shows 'with Google APIs' option for pre API-21 AVDs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I tried creating many different AVDs with different SDK versions ranging from Jelly Bean to ICS to Lollipop. 
Tried both ARM and Intel AVDs
But never once saw Google Play enabled images as an option despite having downloaded those image versions (eg. API-17 armv7 image with Google APIs) except for Lollipop & upwards.
Images below
[image]
[image]

This is really frustrating. 
I saw SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289540/how-to-create-avd-with-google-api-for-intel-x86-atom-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916861/android-avd-device-wont-use-a-google-api-target-and-intel-cpu-at-the-same-time) but they're not really relevant (am using Studio & have already tried ARM images)

How can I create for eg. an API-17 with Google APIs AVD in Android Studio ?

Comment: Check the Show downloadable system images box and see if you have the option to install it.

Comment: I tried that also, it downloads but the 'with Play Services' option still magically remains missing. I also tried restarting after downloading etc but no help